# Cannot set value in chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have no idea why I can't set a value in `chrome.storage.sync` (same issue with `storage.local`), I've tried multiple solutions online, but sadly none of them work

This is my `popup.js` file (linked to the `popup.html` file)

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let my_key = "some string";
    let value = "some value"

    chrome.storage.sync.set({[my_key]: value}, function() {
        console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
    });

    chrome.storage.sync.get([my_key], function(result) {
        console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
    });
});
```

Everytime the output is `Value currently is undefined`.

Comment: The API is asynchronous, which is why it uses callbacks. You should call get inside the callback of set. Also result.key should be result[my_key]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `result[my_key]` not `result.key`

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get([my_key], function(result) {
        console.log('Value currently is ' + result[my_key]);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic keys you have to set the variable in brackets: `{[my_key]: value}` and also set a value for `value`.

Comment: Hello, after defining the value for `value` and changing to `{[my_key}: value}` it still prints out `undefined`